How to effectively ungroup apps in windows 11 taskbar
I have browsed this thread before posting this message because my question is a bit more specific.
I have found the option to "Never combine taskbar buttons and hide labels" in taskbar settings as you can see in the picture bellow.

The problem is this doesn't "unclump" those items in the sense that you can't place one before the other individually. When you try to move one of the "ungroupped" instances of the program, all the other instances move in the taskbar aswell. (See gif I attached)

Do I have to install third-party software like Start11 to do this?
I know there existed an option on 7+ taskbar tweaker to achieve this, but this excellent portable software is not compatible with windows 11, and I don't want to install something using root level access on my pc... (work computer)

it's stupid, but i'm trying to find a solution
